# Resize image preserving exif data: focal length etc

Tags: photo, image-resizing, exif, exiftool

What converter(like imagemagick) can be used to convert images with exif data preserving it?

What if I downscale images 4 times? Should I also change the focal length?

Data I have extracted from my JPG photo with `exiftool`

```
Focal Length                    : 50.0 mm (35 mm equivalent: 50.0 mm)
```

**EDIT:**
Seems imagemagick preserve exif data:

`mogrify -resize 25% -path output_foler/ *.JPG`

Comment: Why do you want to change the focal length as that is lens data. No matter what size the image is the focal length will be the same. Also your question is to broad asking for some software especially with out specifying more details.

Comment: @Bonzo Seems focal length matter for photogrammetry software http://www.agisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=5763.msg28099#msg28099

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe newer versions of Imagemagick should preserve the metadata.  A fall back would be to use Exiftool to copy the data with a command like `exiftool -tagsfromfile OldFile -all:all NewFile`.

Both of those are platform independent.  To be more precise with other programs, you will need specify your OS.  For example, with Windows, you can use Irfanview to convert images and it will retain most metadata as long as you enable those options.

Comment: Would be good to know as of which version ImageMagick supports the preservation of the metadata.